# Which cloud system to choose for spring-mvc project deployment

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, cloud, web-deployment

In my company we are working on a **spring-mvc** based product. We currently deploy projects .war file in tomcat 7 on a server machine (which has its own static ip) to access it globally while the database ( oracle ) is on a different machine.This server machine and db machine are currently in my office.

So basically when we need to access the project outside of our office we access the static ip of serve machine.

Now I have been told by my project manager to find a way to **deploy .war of the spring-mvc project on a cloud based system**.I don't have the slightest clue where to begin.

What I need is any guidance / document / tutorial which can help on getting started.

Which cloud based system will be best for me to do so? Should I use **Convrgd** or **AWS [Elastic Beanstalk Or EC2]** or any other service?

[ Note: I know this is a opinion based question but what I want is opinion on which I could begin to get a clean idea of which path should choose. ]

Let me know if you need any additional information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely it is a good idea to move your application to the cloud.

There are many cloud service provider(s) are offering the cloud services now a days which you can make use of. like AWS, Azure, Rackspace etc.

Rightnow, AWS is in the leader position in the cloud space. Definitely, you can give a try in Amazon Web Services.

Elastic Beanstalk is a container service where you can easily deploy your application (war) file. Just upload a war file, AWS will launch Load balancer, Auto Scaling on your behalf.
For the database, for now you can launch a Amazon RDS (with Oracle). Transfer the data copy from your existing database to the Amazon RDS.

Hope this helps.

Note:
AWS costs you based on the type of the instance, database per hour basis.